# Time series prediction: Neural Network (nnetar) vs. exponential smoothing (ets)

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

When I make a forecast for the univariate time series $x_1=1, x_2=2, \dots, x_{14} = 14$, why does the `nnetar()` function in R (which uses a neural network) not calculate correct results, whereas `ets()` (which uses exponential smoothing) does?

```
library(forecast)
df <- (1:14)
fit<-nnetar(df)

fc<-forecast(fit,h=10)
```

Result:
14.75729410
15.37348413
15.85274344
16.21147877
16.47188350
16.65653700
16.78524210
16.87385438
16.93433975
16.97538111

```
fit2 <- ets(df)
fc <- forecast(fit2,h=10)
```

Result:
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24

Which is the appropriate neuronal network / function for time series prediction? Please consider that the above example is just a simplified data-example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> which is the appropriate neuronal network / function for time series prediction? Please consider, that above example is just a simplified data-example.

Well, this totally depends on your data. In your example data you have

- a small univariate time series (only 14 observations)
- a linear trend
- no white noise
- no seasonality
- no cycle
- non non-linearity

**nnetar()**

Neural networks are generally very data savvy/ data hungry. That means that you need a lot of data to implement an accurate forecast. 14 observations are definitely not enough you rather need some ten or hundred thousands. In general, I do not recommend using neural networks for forecasting univariate time series. One benefit of neural networks is that they can capture nonlinearities, but your data does not exhibit any nonlinearity. Note that `nnetar()` uses a feed-forward neural network; in recent time series forecasting many researchers use recurrent neural networks instead of feed-forward neural networks.

You can also read [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2213).  As far as I know `nnetar()` is based on the discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181)

If you print `fit` you will see the model. It is an average of 20 different neural networks and therefore not deterministic.

```
Series: df 
Model:  NNAR(1,1) 
Call:   nnetar(y = df)

Average of 20 networks, each of which is
a 1-1-1 network with 4 weights
options were - linear output units 

sigma^2 estimated as 0.003636
```

**ets()**

This function uses exponential smoothing. Exponential smoothing models require fewer parameters. Therefore they perform better on your tiny dataset.

It might help to have a closer look at the equations of simple exponential smoothing:

$s_0 = x_0$

$s_t = \alpha x_t + (1- \alpha) s_{t-1}$

In your case $s_0$ and $x_0$ are 0.

If you print `fit2` you can see that the information criteria are all equal to minus infinity which states that there is no better model than the one you have chosen.

```
ETS(A,A,N) 

Call:
 ets(y = df) 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 0.5445 
    beta  = 0.1009 

  Initial states:
    l = 0 
    b = 1 

  sigma:  0

 AIC AICc  BIC 
-Inf -Inf -Inf
```

Comment: what is s? s=y?

Comment: s=y. In other words s is the output of the exponential smoothing algorithm.

Comment: why do i get "Average of 20 networks, each of which is
a 8-4-1 network with 41 weights (Model:  NNAR(8,4) )". AND: thx for all, but I know this kindness of saying "Thank you" is not apprciated by the admins. They alway delete it, thats why i dont write in usually....

Comment: do you get an 8-4-1 network on your real data or on the above shown simplified data?

Comment: sorry, my fault. you are right. its NNAR(1,1)

Comment: what is meant by "...therefore not deterministic"

Comment: There is a bayesian approach of averaging many different networks. I refer to AdamO s great answer on your question.

Comment: Please note that if your data is different from the simple example data an other model might fit better.

Comment: @flobrr "not deterministic": the model assumptions behind the nnetar do not model the process, so the differences between predictions and observed values are taken (incorrectly) to be noise in the model.

Comment: ok, based on this https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/nnetar-prediction-intervals/ i thought nnetar is also appropriat for linear univariate time series data

Comment: In my experience you will be better of with ets, arima or tbats. I am not stating this due to any research, but owing to my experience as practicionner.

Comment: +1, nice answer! When you write that NNs are "data savvy", do you mean "data hungry" or "greedy"?

Comment: Yes Stephan. I just edited my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the data generating process is a deterministic model. This is a special case of an ARIMA(0,1,1) process, also known as exponential smoothing. Therefore the exponential smoothing model generates forecasts that match your expectation. The autoregressive neural network does not model this type of process.